# File added to cpanel is not updated

Tags: cpanel

I added a new php file to directory with my theme. But, I am unable to see it on the internet.
When I edit a working file from same directory, it works.

Moreover, I added a new page from wordpress dashboard. I do not see the corresponding file on cpanel.

Comment: When adding a new page into your wordpress, the page is added in the wordpress data (a mysql database). That wordpress page is not added as a file on your account. So it's pretty logical that you won't see that file. As for the php file within your theme directory, it depends how you have added it and how you try to see it on internet.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a problem with authorization.
The default permission scheme should be:

```
Folders - 755
Files - 644
```